# Delete inserted MySQL record after certain amount of seconds

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, intervals

I am having a MySQL table called `products_reservations` where I insert data when a user clicks a button to put something to his shopping card. Those products should get reserved for a certain amount of time. The table has a column called `timestamp` where the exact date and time in the format `2018-10-22 21:29:16` gets saved after clicking the button for reserving. Now I want to set an interval to delete the record in the `products_reservations` table after exactly 21.600 seconds or 6 hours in the same PHP script. My query by now looks like the following:

```
 // ADD RESERVATION
 $ins = $c->prepare("INSERT INTO products_reserved (uid,pid,timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)");
 $ins->bind_param('sss', $uid, $id, $timestamp);
 $ins->execute();

 $needid = $ins2->insert_id;
 $timestampSeconds = strtotime($timestamp);

 // SET INTERVAL FOR 6 HOURS                   
 $delIntv = $c->prepare("
    DELETE FROM products_reserved 
    WHERE ? = (? + INTERVAL 21600 SECOND) 
    AND id = ?
 ");
 $delIntv->bind_param('sss', $timestampSeconds, $timestampSeconds, $needid);
 $delIntv->execute();

 if($ins && $delIntv) {
    $c->commit();
 }
```

I know I am doing it totally wrong, or rather I would bet for it. Haven't found anything helpful by now tho. Any idea?

Comment: Use a `cron` job.

Comment: I'm assuming this could be for multiple products. Do you have multiple databases or just one? I'd look at using a cron for this to delete all records that meet your criteria in a batch job rather than just each individually, you can set it to run every 5 mins or any interval you like

Comment: Never heard of those cron jobs, any reference?

Comment: All over the freaking Internet. Type "cron job" into Google for gosh sakes.

Comment: You could look into [Temporary tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) or [Stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html). I would also suggest to maybe re-think your approach. If you will be deleting these reservations you are losing data that could be handy in the future. Instead, you could do the comparison in your app (SELECT based on timestamp + your desired threshold). That way you will keep the reservations and maintain your logic as well.

Comment: Haha yeah I will

Comment: Rather than trying to delete reservations after exactly 6 hours, you're better off having the reservations automatically expire simply by adding `WHERE timestamp < <six hours ago>` to your query that looks for valid reservations. Then you eliminate the need to delete them with precise timing. In fact, you eliminate the need to delete them at all -- perhaps knowing what people have reserved would be useful to you.

Comment: I don't think that you can do that in the same script, you should create other script that just delete the rows and schedule the script to run in the background (using cron).

Comment: Maybe you could store this data in the session instead of database.

Comment: I guess my decision is going to be the cronjob. This looks pretty nice and easy! Thank you tho

Comment: You can also use the MySQL [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)